# Pandas or Spark: Generate summarize(aggregated) table from raw data and map rows of agg results to columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

Got few column need to be created, I'm considering do it with pandas or pyspark, I got million small table that each contains timeseries tables for particular sensor, and I want create a summary table that has some statistic calculated. The result would be each row represent a summary info for the raw data like groupby "sensor's uuid".

Below question is for a single such sensor data. I want it generate a row of pandas Dataframe, or a list of values then I can append to create a Dataframe if getting dataframe is hard.

1. For single file it's like below table, I want to do some complex group calculation and get one single row of summary data. I'm current doing this pythonic way, I want transfer to pandas or pyspark more concise way, you can see from my code it's only return it as single numeric value. I want something that what `group.agg()` did.
2. I want iteratively create some column like I showed in result table. From `df.groupby("b").agg(avg=("y", "mean"), cnt=("b", "count")).reset_index()` table will be like below; but that is row-wise, and I want convert it to column-wised with pandas's method(I can do it with a `for` loop in python and append those result to a list then create a `Dataframe` from it, but that is not elegant). More detail in result table.

```
b   avg cnt
0   0.26    6
1   0.23    3
2   0.69    2
```

**Raw table:**

```
y   a   b
1   0   1
0   2   0
1   0   2
1   0   2
0   4   0
1   0   1
0   6   0
0   6   0
0   6   0
1   0   1
0   8   0
```

My function to get such data

```py
def get_stats(df):
    g = df.groupby("a").size()
    c = g.count()
    a = df["y"].sum()
    b = df["y"].count()

    avg_col = (b - a) / (c - 1)
    min_col = g.min()
    max_col = g.max()

    return avg_col, min_col, max_col
```

**The result I want:**

| avg_col | min_col | max_col | col_0(cnt) | col_1(cnt) | col_2(cnt) | col_3(cnt) | ... | col_n(cnt) | col_0(avg) | col_1(avg) | col_2(avg) | ... | col_n(avg) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.5 | 1 | 5 | 6 | 3 | 2 | 0 | ... | 0 | 0.26 | 0.23 | 0.69 | ... | 0 |

Comment: could you  please add more clarity on the question ?

how the output should look like?

Comment: @Deku07 I want to map those aggregated rows to columns like I shown above, frist 3 cols generated by the function I posted, rest generated question.2, but the column is not directly maped, i want create fixed num of columns and fill the column when the agg result appears. and others default as 0s.

Comment: @Deku07 Which part is not clear to you, I will explain more